# Finding particular solution to the harmonic oscillator using variations of constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had to calculate the general solution to the equation for harmonic oscillator: 
$$\ddot{z}+\frac{f}{m}\cdot z = g + \frac{fz_0}{m},$$

here $g$ being the gravitational constant, $f$ being the frequency, $m$ being the mass and $z_0$ being the "idle state" of the spring. Let $\omega^2 = \frac{f}{m}$

I calculated the homogeneous solution:

$$z_h(t)=A\cdot \cos(\omega\cdot t - \varphi)$$

To get the general solution, I also need the particular/special solution. My approach for getting the particular was variation of constants, so I treated $A$ as time dependent:

Ansatz: 
\begin{align} z(t)&=A\cdot \cos(\omega\cdot t - \varphi) \\
\Rightarrow \dot z (t)&=A'(t)\cos(\omega\cdot t - \varphi) - \omega A(t)\sin(\omega\cdot t - \varphi)\\
\Rightarrow \ddot z(t)&=A''(t)\cos(\omega\cdot t - \varphi) - \omega A'(t)\sin(\omega\cdot t - \varphi) \\
&\ \ - \omega A'(t)\sin(\omega\cdot t - \varphi)-\omega^2A(t)\cos(\omega\cdot t - \varphi)\end{align}

We now put that into our differential equation to get:

$$A''(t)\cos(\omega\cdot t - \varphi) - \omega A'(t)\sin(\omega\cdot t - \varphi) - \omega A'(t)\sin(\omega\cdot t - \varphi)-\omega^2A(t)\cos(\omega\cdot t - \varphi) + \omega^2A\cdot \cos(\omega\cdot t - \varphi)=g+\omega z_0$$

The last two terms cancel out:

$$A''(t)\cos(\omega\cdot t - \varphi) - \omega A'(t)\sin(\omega\cdot t - \varphi) - \omega A'(t)\sin(\omega\cdot t - \varphi)=g+\omega z_0.$$

I expected the other two $\sin$ terms to be cancelled out as well but it seems that doesn't happen, so I'm still left with a differential equation.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: When using variation of parameters for higher order differential equations could be quite tricky, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#Specific_second_order_equation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try instead $z(t)=A\cos(\omega t-\varphi)+C$, where $A$ and $C$ are constants. You should get $$\frac{f}{m} C= g+\frac{fz_0}{m}$$ 
You approach is not wrong, just that it does not lead to the desired solution

Comment: I'm goign to try it, a little question: If the Right Hand Side would be a constant, wouldn't there be a very easy way to solve it?

Comment: Yes. Just add a constant to your homogeneous solution. That's what I did. It will disappear from the term with derivatives, and will just be in the term proportional to $z$

Comment: I don't get it. Ansatz: $z_h(t)=A\cos(\omega t -\varphi) + C$ then $\dot z_h(t)=-\omega A \sin(\omega t -\varphi)$ and $\ddot z_h(t)=-\omega^2A \cos(\omega t -\varphi)$ If I put that all into my origina lequation, I get $A\cos(\omega t -\varphi)[\omega - \omega^2] + C = g + \omega^2z_0$. Gues you didn't mean that with "try"?

Comment: It is not $[\omega-\omega^2]$ but $[\omega^2-\omega^2]$. You have $\frac{f}{m}=\omega^2$

Comment: of course, yeah. Just out of curiosity: Do you have an idea why my approach didn't work out? What's the reason? What if the inhomogenity was time dependent? Thanks!

Comment: I think your approach just complicates the problem. Not sure I would be able to solve that equation.